# setMethod distinguish between using to "assign" to variable and pure "info" call

Tags: r, r-s4

Anyone know if the following can be achieved in R specifically S4

```
foo <- setClass("foo", contains = "matrix")
foo <- function(m = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)) new("foo", m)

setMethod("dim", signature = "foo", 
  function(x) {
       dd <- dim(x@.Data)
       cat("foo dims: ")
       return(dd)
}
)

# followed by  
bar <- foo()
```

#### How or can it be achieved to distinguish between ...

```
dim(bar)
# which gives
foo dims: [1] 3 3 
# and calling dim to assign the return value to a variable 
# ie this call
bardims <- dim(bar)
# which does 
foo dims: 
# but I don't want it to produce any cat output to the console/screen
```

in the second case I would like to suppress the `cat(....)` part of the original "dim,foo-method".
I would not mind defining something like `setMethod('<-dim', 'foo', function(....` but I guess that is not available?
Info: I am using R-4.0.5 here

Comment: It is perfectly possible to create assignment methods, but the function is called `dim<-` rather than `<-dim`.

Comment: I know; but the goal here is a different one ... I am trying to find a way to be able to change the output based on: if I am calling `dim` just to see the dims and then being verbose in its output and a "silent" version of it, when I am assigning the value of `dim(object)` to a DIFFERENT variable - ie I am not 'assigning' a value to the dimensions of the object itself but using that value somewhere later on and don't want verbosity at the Console or anywhere else; 
MrFlick's answer achieves exactly that -> which is quite cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a great idea to use `cat()` to spit out messages in function. It gives users very little control over how they display and makes it very difficult to grab those values should they ever want them.

A possible alternative is to annotate the response with a custom class that will output a message only when `print()`-ed. Hence it will not show up during assignment because those results are returned invisibly.

Here's an S3 class that can help

```
annotate_value <- function(val, msg) {
  attr(val, "message") <- msg
  class(val) <- c("annotated", class(val))
  val
}
print.annotated <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "annotated")
  cat(attr(x, "message"))
  attr(x, "message") <- NULL
  print(x)
}
```

And then you use it like

```
setMethod("dim", signature = "foo", 
          function(x) {
            dd <- dim(x@.Data)
            annotate_value(dd, "foo dims:")
          }
)
```

Then when you run your code, you get the desired output

```
bar <- foo()
dim(bar)
# foo dims:[1] 3 3
bardims <- dim(bar)
#
```

Comment:  looks quite promising, but let me sleep over it ...  already thank you for pointing me in a good direction; since it's already quite late here, I will accept the answer afterwards or at least will upvote it, just in case something "nicer" pops up during my absence, which tbh I don't think will happen
Thanks a lot